# RDC drops at "estimating connection quality" - Terminal Server, Remote Desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, terminal-server

When trying to connect to our Win 2012 R2 Terminal Server via RDC, the connection process gets to the **"estimating connection quality"** step and just disconnects.

The Terminal Server was working all okay until the host died. We since then migrated the Terminal Server VM onto a new host, from which this issue appears to have started to happen.

*Have tried re-isntalling VMWare Tools and removed then re-added the network interface but no such luck.*

Also migrated a different Windows Server VM to the new host and can confirm RDC still works on that VM as expected, so i don't believe it has anything to do with the actual host..

Wondering what other trouble shooting steps i can try? (Terminal Service licensing looks all good as well)

Answer (score -1):

ahh, the resolution was very easy - make sure your server time is in sync and correct!

Incorrect date & time can cause various issues, especially with servers that are talking to Active Directory.

Comment: Some explanation as to how to do this would make a better answer.